# Does mysql error in inserting unique record terminate foreach loop on first error?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I am inserting mySQL result into table which has unique index on account number and trasaction date

```
foreach ($fulldata as $partdata){
       $name=$partdata['name'];
       $acno=$partdata['acno'];
       $trdate=$partdata['trdate'];
       $sql="INSERT into mytable (name,acno,trdate) values ('$name','$acno','$trdate')";
       $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

If the entry is duplicate, the error is shown 'duplicate entry on...' and the loop is terminated. It does not take up next record for processing even if it does not have duplicate values with existing records in the database.

Ideally, it should show error for only those rows which has duplicate entry but insert all those records which are unique new entries. Can any other type  of loop help ?

Comment: One alternative is to make MySQLi throw exceptions, and catch those. Or, instead of using `or die(mysqli_error($con))`, use a check (if-statement) and check the error-code. It's stopping because you `die()` when an error occurs.

Comment: This is not an answer but setting unique on date feels weird.

Comment: @DaveTeu, if you have situation where an account must have only one transaction on a given date, how do you enforce table not to accept data again for that account on that day again ?

Comment: I would have done a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE acno = $acno and trdate = $trdate even before the transaction gets accepted and not during a the time where the database gets updated in bulk. But i'm sure you have your reasons and limitation to be doing what you are doing.

Comment: @DaveTeu, The 'foreach' loop in this case comes with over 50,000 accounts to be updated. If you do count(*) from mytable WHERE acno=$acno and if count is >1 means you already have duplication. Before addition of duplicate record takes place, count(*) has nothing to do. How then, your suggestion will prevent a duplicate entry ?

Comment: @HeenaShah no, i meant what I would have done is to check before i accept a transaction. In your scenario you would have already accepted the transaction for the day, and updating in bulk. In your scenario the Count would not work.. but the accepted answer will do just what you need. :)

Comment: @DaveTeu, Your suggestion was perfect not to accept transaction in the first place. For sake of understanding accounting scenario how such requirement arise, let me go further. It is not customer transaction which calls for this situation. but here we are applying calculated interest to customer account. Some clerks were feeding same interest calculation sheets to system again by mistake. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a try/catch approach to echo out the statements. But I use PDO.

```
foreach ($fulldata as $partdata){
       $name=$partdata['name'];
       $acno=$partdata['acno'];
       $trdate=$partdata['trdate'];
       $sql="INSERT into mytable (name,acno,trdate) values (?,?,?)";

       try {

            $query = $db->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute(array($name, $acno, $trdate));

       } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            echo 'Fail to execute following statement: ' . $sql ."\r\n";    
      }    
}
```

Now I will also which insert statement fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
  INSERT INTO mytable (name,acno,trdate) VALUES ('$name','$acno','$trdate')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=name;
```

or `INSERT IGNORE INTO`:

```
  INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable (name,acno,trdate) VALUES ('$name','$acno','$trdate')
```

Comment: I was confused which answer to accept. Yours would also serve the purpose with only one drawback that I wanted to know which record had generated error, the reason I used mysqli_error() to see. Accepted answer from @dave-teu has that extra.